# LQFP package vs. TQFP package?

Tags: pcb, tqfp

In my PCB editor, both LQFP and TQFP have the same footprints, except the TQFP has shorter leads than the LQFP. Is that the only difference?

Comment: My advice would be to never, ever, use those sort of names to actually match a PCB footprint to a device. Always, always check the dimensions.

Comment: There are industry standards in footprints though...I'd just do a few sanity spot-checks to make sure it's not totally off then grab the library footprint. A 0.4 mm wide land vs. 0.38 mm seldom matters.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

L is for Low-profile (1.4 mm) and T is for thin(er, 1.0 mm), so I think the only definitive difference between them is height.  The pitch and package size can vary within each.

Comment: [LQFP Dimensions and Characteristics](http://www.practicalcomponents.com/Dummy-Components/product.cfm?Low-Profile-Quad-Flat-Pack-%28LQFP%29-Dummy-Component-C716B832B0D1821D) vs. [TQFP Dimensions and Characteristics](http://www.practicalcomponents.com/Dummy-Components/product.cfm?Thin-Quad-Flat-Pack-%28TQFP%29-Dummy-Component-9A06B8579E20A566)