# TQFP vs QFP landpattern

Tags: packages, footprint, tqfp

I know these packages have different thickness, but I have a hard time to find a TQFP landpad spec. Is it using the same landpad as for QFP (reflow soldering)?

Comment: What does your datasheet say?

Comment: My datasheet says TQFP but has no recommended land pattern. And when I Google there is no usable TQFP land pattern to find. So I was thinking that maybe TQFP have the same land pattern as QFP.

Comment: It is better to design own land pattern based on your design requirements. There's a standard IPC-7351A which describes method to design land patters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only difference between TQFP and QFP is the thickness, see related questions [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/6191/lqfp-package-vs-tqfp-package?rq=1) and [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/26879/what-is-the-difference-between-vqfp-hvqfp-tqfp-pqfp?rq=1).

However that doesn't mean that all QFP or TQFP packages are the same.  They can have different pin pitch (the distance between pins) and perhaps even a different package size.

If you update your question with the part it might be possible to help further.  Some manufacturers do not give package information in every datasheet but instead have a catalogue of land patterns in a different document.

If you can't find a land pattern from the IC manufacturer then check very carefully the pin pitch and package size when trying to find a compatible footprint.

Comment: Thank you, I'm aware of the different pitch variations. But you confirmed what I suspected, TQFP can be placed on a QFP land pattern IF they have the same pitch :)

Comment: Seems like a silly thing to assume when 15 minutes of research can give you the exact answer and prevent a time consuming error.